# Get values inside ArrayList in specific order

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists as below ,

```
 private List<Patienthealthdata> patientHealthDataList = new ArrayList<Patienthealthdata>();
public List<Patienthealthdata> getPatientHealthDataList() {patientHealthDataSet = medicalHistoryService.getLatestMedicalHistoryDataAttributes(patient);Map<Integer, String> heightMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
        List<Patienthealthdata> PatienthealthdataDummy = new ArrayList<Patienthealthdata>();
        PatienthealthdataDummy.addAll(patientHealthDataSet);
        for (int i = 0; i < PatienthealthdataDummy.size(); i++) {
            if (PatienthealthdataDummy.get(i).getHealthdata().getName().contains("Height (ft)")) {
                heightMap.put(1, PatienthealthdataDummy.get(i).getHealthDataValue());if (PatienthealthdataDummy.get(i).getHealthdata().getName().contains("Height (in)")) {
                heightMap.put(2, PatienthealthdataDummy.get(i).getHealthDataValue());}for (Patienthealthdata patientHealthData : patientHealthDataSet) { 
            String valHeightInch = "";
            String valHeightFt = "";
            String newValue = "";
            String groupName = patientHealthData.getHealthdata().getHealthdatagrouplinks().iterator().next().getHealthdatagroup().getName().trim();
            if (groupName.equals(Constants.HELTH_GROUP_BMI)) {
                if (patientHealthData.getHealthdata().getName().contains("Height (ft)")) { for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : heightMap.entrySet()) {if (entry.getKey() == 1) {
                            valHeightFt = entry.getValue();}
                        if (entry.getKey() == 2) {
                            valHeightInch = entry.getValue();
                        }}patientHealthDataList.add(patientHealthData); 
            } //End of If condition
```

i would like to sort them in desired order on retrieving . Any help is appreciated

Comment: Don't put an entire question in the title, and, give us more information. In the body.

Comment: I don't see any ArrayLists, I only see an unordered map.

Comment: please help any one i stuck two day

Comment: array list define the folowing type  private List<Patienthealthdata> patientHealthDataList = new ArrayList<Patienthealthdata>();

Comment: Can you, like, I don't know, use translator or pay someone to write your question in english? It doesn't make any sense..

Comment: please keyser help of this task

Comment: @user3460915 try my updated answer

Comment: i runnig this code our three field Height,weight,Bmi three field not get in desired order it change every time when run the project

Comment: I tried to edit it. Revert it if it doesn't make sense

Comment: san krish where are u show your update answer ?

Comment: @user3460915 replace your `for` loop as i mentioned in my update

Comment: no sir in your loop key is define string the string is not accept

Comment: our map look like defind this type Map<Integer, String> heightMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();

Comment: please sir help of this task

Comment: san krish sir i update my code more foremally plz check it and  help

Comment: mareckmareck sir i have update more formally please check it

Comment: keyser i update my question plz check it

Comment: san krish for this code i am not getting Height value and  order is  first field is Height second is BMI last is Weight but my requirment is first height second weight third is BMI

Comment: san krish your above code i have not get desired ouput

Answer (score 0):

From your title,

Use an iterator

```
Iterator<E> iterator()
```

to retrieve the elements in the insertion order

And as @Keyser said where is the arraylist first ?

**Update:**

To sort your map, use this

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : heightMap.entrySet())
```

A `LinkedHashMap` keeps the keys in the order they were inserted, while a `TreeMap` is kept sorted via a Comparator or the natural Comparable ordering of the elements.

Comment: hello descibre more formmaly plz help any body

Comment: hello sir i using your for loop the value is not change in every time when our project is run it is good but our desire order is not get

Comment: That depends on type of map . You could use [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html‎) for sorting

Comment: sir i using Tree map but not get desire order

Comment: my order is first Height,Weight third field BMI but this order not get

Comment: If you want to get the order you specified then insert it in the same order and try with `LinkedHashMap`

Comment: Also make sure that you insert them in the order you specified (i.e) `Height,Weight third field BMI`

Comment: krish sir My order is same as Height ,Weight ,BMI but not get through linked hash map and Tree map